# How come the "SerialNumber" property of the "Win32_CDROMDrive" class returns null when asking for it separately from WMI?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, wmi, wql

When acquiring the value of the property `SerialNumber` from the WMI class `Win32_CDROMDrive` like this `SELECT SerialNumber FROM Win32_CDROMDrive` it throughs a `NullReferenceException` unless i change the query to `SELECT * FROM Win32_CDROMDrive`. Then loop arround all the properties including the `SerialNumber` in-which in that case is not null.

And since the first method is faster than the second (not quite sure) I prefer to use it. So what is happening? Am I missing something?
Note that it works perfectly fine with other properties and classes!

**This is my code**

```
string result = "";
var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT SerialNumber FROM Win32_CDROMDrive");
ManagementObjectCollection collec = searcher.Get();
foreach (ManagementObject obj in collec)
{
    result = obj["SerialNumber"].ToString();
    break;
}
MessageBox.Show(result);
```

It won't work unless i change to:

```
var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_CDROMDrive");
```

**Update**

The first method works with the other properties of the same class and the value can be extracted without an exception. It seems like the problem is with the `SerialNumber` property only!

**Update 2**

It seems like the problem is indeed with just `SerialNumber` as looping arround all the non-nulled-values of properties of the `Win32_CDROMDrive` will list the `SerialNumber` with a real value as the code below explains:

```
listView1.Items.Clear();
var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_CDROMDrive");
foreach (ManagementObject mo in searcher.Get())
{
    foreach (PropertyData pd in mo.Properties)
    {
        if (pd.Value != null)
            listView1.Items.Add(pd.Name).SubItems.Add(pd.Value.ToString());
    }
}
```

However, if the query is changed to the specific wanted property method it will give the same error!

**Update 3**

I managed to get the value of this naughty property without looping arround all the remaining ones via a different class `Win32_PhysicalMedia` which contains less properties for all connected drives (*HDD, ODD, Floppy, ...*) including the `SerialNumber` property using this WQL query

`SELECT * FROM Win32_PhysicalMedia`

Or to be specific (to the CDROMDrive)

`SELECT * FROM Win32_PhysicalMedia WHERE Tag Like '%CD%'`

Or to be specific (to the `SerialNumber` of the `CDROMDrive`

`SELECT SerialNumber FROM Win32_PhysicalMedia WHERE Tag Like '%CD%'`

```
var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT SerialNumber FROM Win32_PhysicalMedia WHERE TAG LIKE '%CD%'");
ManagementObjectCollection collec = searcher.Get();
foreach (ManagementObject obj in collec)
{
     Console.WriteLine(obj["SerialNumber"].ToString());
}
Console.Read();
```

But i can't consider this to be an answer as my question is why WQL doesn't allow specifing a record inside the `SELECT` statement to the (and only the) `SerialNumber` property of the `CDROMDrive` class?

Answer (score 0):

I just tested on my PC and on my case it seems to be because `SerialNumber` property is null on the only instance I have. As it seems, WMI is no working properly when looking for a property that is NULL (that is on my case).

Anyway, you can use [ORMi](https://github.com/nicoriff/ORMi) to work with WMI and do all the work using Linq.

Example:

```
WMIHelper helper = new WMIHelper("root\\CimV2");

var data = helper.Query("SELECT * FROM Win32_CDROMDrive").Where(p => p.SerialNum == "yourSerialNum");
```

Comment: Try the updated 2 code, the serial is not null! it is there, but can be extracted only if extracting all the properties' values then looping arround the required one

Comment: Yes... it seems that there is an issue where there are instances with null values even if there is non null values... strange behavior

Comment: Plus i'm more interested of knowing the reason why this happens more than how can it happen alternatively. As i did get the serial already except with the (incorrect method).