# How to SELECT a single field from a Win32 WMI class?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, wmi, wql

[Win32 Classes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394084(v=vs.85).aspx) in Windows OS are groups of [Hardware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/CIMWin32Prov/computer-system-hardware-classes), Software or OS [classes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/WmiSdk/wmi-classes) (along with others) that contains features and attributes depending on the class selected. My problem is with the [Win32_CDROMDrive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/CIMWin32Prov/win32-cdromdrive) that has many properties of the connected ODD device like `Caption`, `Description`, `Drive`, `Id`, `Name`, etc.). The problem (specifically) is with the property `SerialNumber` which returns the identifier of the drive by the manufacture. **It returns a null** in a case **and returns an actual value** in a different case! The code will walk you through:

Here is how to list all the properties of the `Win32_CDROMDrive` (`SerialNumber` exist with an actual value).

```
var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_CDROMDrive");
foreach (ManagementObject mo in searcher.Get())
    foreach (PropertyData pd in mo.Properties)
        Console.WriteLine("{0}:- {1}", pd.Name, pd.Value);
```

To get a single property value (like `Name`) from the same class the query is changed to (and it will return the value of `Name`).

```
var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT Name FROM Win32_CDROMDrive");
```

To get the value of the `SerialNumber` property the query is changed to (and here is the problem, it will return **null** while **did not before**!)

```
var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT SerialNumber FROM Win32_CDROMDrive");
```

More odd behavior is when I try to get the value of a property with other random one like this (it will return actual values for both `Name` and `SerialNumber`)

```
var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT SerialNumber, SCSIPort FROM Win32_CDROMDrive");
```

While if with a property with a different initial (it will return **null** for the `SerialNumber` and actual value for the `Name`)

```
var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT SerialNumber, Name FROM Win32_CDROMDrive");
```

I know I’ve asked a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51189508/how-come-the-serialnumber-property-of-the-win32-cdromdrive-class-returns-nul) but I can’t delete it or edit it to this one (which what I have got so far) cause it has good information that might be helpful for someone (even if it is simple).

I just want to get the `SerialNumber` solely like this `SELECT SerialNumber FROM Win32_CDROMDrive` without extracting the whole values and choosing between them.